# Do virtual desktops using VirtualBox have their own mouse cursors?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, mouse, winapi

Say I have a virtual desktop with Windows 10 installed using VirtualBox and create an application that runs on that desktop. The application in question will take control of the cursor using SendInput() in the WINAPI.

Will the cursor on the virtual desktop be affected? Or will my main mouse (on the host) be affected, or won't it work at all?

Comment: I would guess that as long as the VM window does not have focus, it will not affect the host mouse...Probably the best way to find out is to try it!

Comment: Thing is, i have only 2 gb space on my host machine so i cant really try haha. Currently just exploring options for my application, whats possible to do and what not.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Machines are (in principle) indistinguishable from physical ones. Windows 10 running inside your VirtualBox guest doesn't realize that it's running on virtual hardware.

VirtualBox creates and emulates a virtual pointing device, either mouse or tablet (depending on VM's configuration) and translates mouse pointer movement in host to virtual mouse movement or tablet pen's movement in the VM.

This design implies that guest OS can't take over host's pointer. Moving guest pointer won't move virtual mouse/tablet, just like moving host's pointer doesn't physically move the mouse.

It *should* be possible to implement this behavior using host-guest communication provided by VirtualBox, but as far as I know nobody has done that yet. What's more, if it was possible, it would be a huge security vulnerability, as it would allow for guest OSes to "escape" from their virtual machines and control host.